# Finding a way to bypass the notification shown by GoDaddy in a chromedriver window in an automation script

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, godaddy-api

I am currently writing an automation script using selenium with java. There, I am trying to get an OTP from the email which the OTP is being sent and I am planning to open a tab in the chromedriver and open the email in that tab. The email account is an office 365 account hosted by GoDaddy and during the attempt of sign in, this [notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsNuq.png) pops up and I am not allowed to continue thereafter.

I want to know a possible way to bypass this notification in the chromedriver.

I tried searching all over the internet and nothing came up.

The following code segment is what I tried to do.

```
public class EmailLoginSteps{
   public static void main(String[] args)
{
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");
      tabs = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
      driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));
      driver.get("https://outlook.office365.com");

      driver.findElement(By.id("i0116")).sendKeys(email+"\n");//replace email with an godaddy hosted office 365 mail address
      Thread.sleep(4000);
      driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys(password+"\n");//replace password with the relevant password
}
```

Comment: Which browser version do you have? I have no problem with connecting to https://outlook.office365.com, using latest chromedriver.
Also, maybe it worth to try to get email via email connector and don't reach UI?

Comment: The Chrome Browser version is Version 114.0.5735.199. Is this what you meant by email connector?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584393/connecting-to-outlook365-from-selenium-java

Comment: I mean, not to connect to email via frontend, but via background email connector that connects to your mailbox, not using UI.

Answer (score 0):

**Using UI to automate email service is not recommended, instead you can use Java mailer API's.**

**To solve the above issue you can use the below hacks:**

1. Add custom user-agent to bypass detection.

**Code:**

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    // Disable the automation message
    options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches",Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
    // Hide the automation status bar
    options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
    // Set the user agent
    options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: It still shows the notification. Also I am not aware about Java mailer APIs. Do you have any sources to get that knowledge?

Comment: @SanchithaJayasuriya https://gist.github.com/brunocribeiro/12a529f7f752f2853b9f